# How to print output horizontally?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement, output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg40a.png)I have written a program using java where if you input name it will print in star pattern. But the output is vertical. i want output horizontally so name is displayed. please help . Here is my code
It looks long but simple code. I am a beginner please help

import java.util.Scanner;

public class patterns {

```
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        static void PrintA() {
        int i,j;
        
        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
            for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                if(((i==2)&&(j==2||j==3||j==4))||((i==4)&&(j==2||j==3||j==4))||((i==5)&&(j==2||j==3||j==4)))
                    System.out.print(" ");
                else
                    System.out.print("*");
                
            }
            
            System.out.println();
        }
        

    }
        static void PrintB() {
            int i,j;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                    if((i==1||i==3||i==5)&&(j<=3))
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else if((i==2||i==4)&&(j==1||j==4))
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            
        }
        static void PrintC() {
            int i,j;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                    if((i==1||i==5)&&(j<=5))
System.out.print("*");
else if((i==2||i==3||i==4)&&(j==1))
    System.out.print("*");
else
    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        static void PrintD() {
            int i,j;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                    if((i==1||i==5)&&(j<=3))
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else if((i==2||i==4)&&(j==4||j==1))
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else if(i==3&&(j==5||j==1))
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        
        static void PrintE() {
            int i,j;
            for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                    if(i%2!=0&&j<=5)
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else if((i>=2 && i<=4) && j==1)
                        System.out.print("*");
                    else
                        System.out.print(" ");
                }
                System.out.println();
                }
        }
        
                    static void PrintF() {
                        int i,j;
                        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                            for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i==1||i==3)&&j<=5)
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if((i>=2&&i<=5)&&j==1)
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
            }
        }
                    static void PrintG() {
                        int i,j;
                        for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                            for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                                if((i==1&&j<=5)||(i==2&&j==1)||(i==3&&(j==1||j>=3))||(i==4&&j%2!=0))
                                    System.out.print("*");
                                else if(i==5&&j!=4)
                                    System.out.print("*");
                                else
                                    System.out.print(" ");
                            }
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                    
                static void PrintH() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&(j==5||j==1))||(i==3&&j<=5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                static void PrintI() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if(((i==1||i==5)&&j<=5)||(i<=5&&j==3))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintJ() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i==1&&j<=5)||(i<=5&&j==3))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if((i==5&&j<=3)||(i==4&&j==1))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintK() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==1)||(i%2==0 && j==3)||((i==1||i==5)&&j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                static void PrintL() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==1)||(i==5&&j<=5))
                            System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                static void PrintM() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5)&&(j==1||j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if((i==2&&(j%2==0))||(i==3&&j==3))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintN() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5)&&(j==1||j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if(i==j)
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintO() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i>=2&&i<=4)&&(j>=2&&j<=4))
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            else
                                System.out.print("*");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintP() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==1)||((i==1||i==3)&&j<=5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if(i==2&&j==5)
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintQ() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=7;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i>=2&&i<=4)&&(j>=2&&j<=4))
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            else if((i==6&&j==4)||(i==7&&j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if((i==6||i==7)&&(j!=4||j!=5))
                                    System.out.print(" ");
                            else
                                System.out.print("*");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                
                static void PrintR() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==1)||((i==1||i==3)&&j<=5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if((i==2&&j==5)||(i==4&&j==4)||(i==5&&j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintS() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
if((i<=3&&j==1)||((i==1||i==3||i==5)&&j<=5)||(i==4&&j==5))
    System.out.print("*");
else
    System.out.print(" ");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintT() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i==1&&j<=5)||(i<=5&&j==3))
                                System.out.print("*");
                        
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintU() {
                    int i,j;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==1)||(i<=5&&j==5))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else if(i==5&&(j>2&&j<4))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintV() {
                    int i,j,n=11;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=10;j++) {
                            if ((i<=5&&j==(n-i))||(i==j))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                            
                        
                        }
                        System.out.println();
    
                    }
                }
                static void PrintW() {
                    int i,j;
                    
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++){
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&(j==1||j==5))||(i==3&&j==3)||(i==4&&j!=3))
                            System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                static void PrintX() {
                    int i,j,n=6;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==(n-i))||(i==j))
                            System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                static void PrintY() {
                    int i,j,n=6;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=3&&j==(n-i))||(i>=3&&j==3)||(i<=3&&i==j))
                                System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
                
                
                static void PrintZ() {
                    int i,j,n=6;
                    for(i=1;i<=5;i++) {
                        for(j=1;j<=5;j++) {
                            if((i<=5&&j==(n-i))||((i==1||i==5)&&j<=5))
                            System.out.print("*");
                            else
                                System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                    
                }
                
                public static void  printinput(char input) {
                    
                    switch (input)
                    {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':
                    PrintA();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'B':
                    case 'b':
                    PrintB();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'C':
                    case 'c':
                    PrintC();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'D':
                    case 'd':
                    PrintD();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                    PrintE();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'F':
                    case 'f':
                    PrintF();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'g':
                    PrintG();
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                    case 'H':
                    case 'h':
                        PrintH();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'I':
                        case 'i':
                        PrintI();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'J':
                        case 'j':
                        PrintJ();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'K':
                        case 'k':
                        PrintK();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'L':
                        case 'l':
                        PrintL();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'M':
                        case 'm':
                        PrintM();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'N':
                        case 'n':
                        PrintN();
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                        case 'O':
                        case 'o':
                            PrintO();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'P':
                            case 'p':
                            PrintP();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'Q':
                            case 'q':
                            PrintQ();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'R':
                            case 'r':
                            PrintR();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'S':
                            case 's':
                            PrintS();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'T':
                            case 't':
                            PrintT();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'U':
                            case 'u':
                            PrintU();
                            System.out.println();
                            break;
                            case 'V':
                            case 'v':
                                PrintV();
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                                case 'W':
                                case 'w':
                                PrintW();
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                                case 'X':
                                case 'x':
                                PrintX();
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                                case 'Y':
                                case'y':
                                PrintY();
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                                case 'Z':
                                case 'z':
                                PrintZ();
                                System.out.println();
                                break;
                            


                    }
                    
                    
                }
            
                
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            
            Scanner Name = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please Enter the Name : ");
            String input = Name.nextLine();
            for(int i=0;i<=input.length()-1;i++) {
                
            printinput(input.charAt(i));
            
            }
            
            
            
        
            
            
            
            
            
        }

}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse tags. That's what design pattern mean in software development https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns

Comment: You will need to have something like a StringBuilder for each row (in an array or list), and append the spaces and stars to each of them instead of using print and println. Then, once all the letters are in there, call System.out.println for each row with the StringBuilder for that row.

Comment: (You could conceivably use `System.setOut(PrintStream)` to replace the standard `System.out` (after saving a reference to it) with one of your own devising which just appended to a row on print, and on println went to the next row, and then you could print them at the end, but I suspect that's beyond where you're at and would be a rather confusing implementation.)